# UART - the clock frequency of the uart transmiter iis different from uart receiver

Tags: uart, baudrate

I use UART between two system (which have 2 proccesors).
The uart of transmiter has clock frequency off 100MHz. and the uart of the receiver has a clock of 125MHz.
The baud rate I use is 1e6.
I can see that in some of the messages there is a bit flip.

Can it be because of the baud rate? Should I use another baud rate?

Comment: Are you saying the UART peripheral in the two systems is set up at different baud rates? Or that the clock frequency of the two processors is different? If the former, then yes, you absolutely must have them at the same baud rate.

Comment: What you should do is proofread your posts. This short question has a ridiculous number of typos, which is annoying and insulting to the people from whom you want advice. Is this really the first impression you want to make?

Comment: @DiBosco- I said that the clock frequency of the two processors is different.

Comment: You did not, you said the transmitter and receiver had different clock frequencies. That is not clear whether you mean the processors or the UART peripherals and you still haven't answered. We're kindly trying to help you, so stop being so defensive and clarify yourself.

Comment: @sarar, you have not specified *in your question* that you have 2 processors. You write about a transmitter and a receiver and, while these could be on 2 different processors, they could also be the tx & rx of a single peripheral on a single processor. Edit your question (don't reply in the comments) and be specific.

Comment: @DiBosco - by all means I didn't mean to be defensive.  I edited the question.

Comment: If your processors are capable of generating baud rates by fractional division it should work as long as the results are within the correct tolerance (as Olin says below). Personally, if I wasn't sure I'd got the registers set correctly to do this, I'd send 0x55 out of each UART, check with the scope how close the baud rates were to each other and how good the waveforms looked. 1M baud rate should though, in theory, be achievable. Are you connecting directly between two micros or going through any sort of interface chip?

Comment: @sarar - There are lots of relevant details which are missing from the story so far e.g. part numbers of the processors, a schematic diagram showing at least the hardware between these two interfaces, the reasons why you chose those different clock speeds for the transmitter & receiver, the reason why you chose that specific baud rate, some examples of the good/bad data showing the bit flip (not all bit flips are "equal" in possible causes), any oscilloscope traces or other test data, information about what test equipment you can access and know how to use etc. Can you supply that information?

Comment: @DiBosco -  the ctransmitter and a receiverv are in different chip. I use the connection of J11 between those chips.

Answer (score 2):

For UART communication, both ends need to run at the same baud rate, ±3% or so for most cases.  3% error allows for ¼ bit time error in the middle of the 8th data bit.

While the UART baud rate is usually derived from the main oscillator of a processor, there is usually the opportunity to divide it down to select 16x the desired baud rate.  For common UART hardware, the internal clock to the UART would therefore need be 16 MHz to achieve 1 MBaud.

Note that neither 100 MHz nor 125 MHz can be divided by a integer and result in 16 MHz ±3%.  You need to check the documentation that what you are trying to do is really possible with the hardware you have.  It could be that neither processor is really running its UART at 1 MBaud.  You likely need a much slower baud rate where 16x the baud rate can be achieved by dividing both the clocks by a integer.

Even if you really are getting 1 MBaud from both ends, keep in mind that such a fast signal won't make it thru common RS-232 converter chips.  Basically, these are just ordinary digital signals between two chips on the same board.

Comment: The divide by 16 is not necessarily an issue; there are a number of micros these days that have UART peripherals with fractional divide to derive the baud rate.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop - So which baud rate do you recommend to use?

Comment: @DiB: It *may* not be a issue, as I said.  However, it is definitely something that needs to be checked, since 16x is very common.

Comment: @sara: As I said, find something that can be derived from both clocks divided by a integer, unless of course you have unusual UART hardware with something like a PLL in its clock chain.  I've never seen that, but it could be out there.  This should all be in the datasheet, of course.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I appreciate you said it may not be an issue, but I respectfully disagree that it's unusual to find fractional divide these days. It's pretty common on modern processors in my experience and you get perfectly adequate accurancy.